# How can I have the ChromeVox extention pronounce all HTML form errors, not just one?

Tags: html, google-chrome, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm curious how to read all errors that appeared when HTML form is filled and the button clicked.

All errors - such as "please enter your middle name", "please enter your age" and so on should be pronounced.

`aria-invalid="true"`, `role="alert"`, `aria-atomic="true"` and their combinations were tested.

It doesn't work at all or works fine, but reads only one error. I need all errors to be pronounced.

Any standard way to do that using HTML?

This question is both for ChromeVox and JAWS.

Comment: What is "Screenbox reader"? And your title says ChromeVox, your tag says Jaws -- about which screen reader(s) is your question?

Comment: Thank you. The question was updated. As far as there is no ChromeVox tag, only JAWS-screen-reader tag was added. JAWS read all errors, ChromeVox read only the first one. I'd like ChromeVox to pronounce all errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).

```html
<form onSubmit="...">
  <input id="username" />
  <span
    aria-live="polite"
    aria-controls="username"
  >Username is required.<span>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Be sure that the element with the `aria-live` attribute exists in the page before the error is dynamically inserted into the element.